# Nonexistent Marker Is Added to Google Maps Android Firebase[VIDEO]

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase

I am pulling marker(relic) data from firebase database then adding them to map. Also i am adding them to another hashmap for doing distance calculations with current user location.Then i calculate closest marker to user and display how far player is to that selected closest marker.When user is closer than 10 meters to marker he can remove that marker from the map.

The problem is i can remove marker from map but whenever i call db removal code somehow db listener triggers and adds Nonexistent removed marker to the map.

```
LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(final Location  location) {


            LatLng latLng;
            latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
            if (playermarker == null) {
                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                markerOptions.position(latLng);
                        markerOptions.title("Thats me!");
                        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.raw.petyr));
                playermarker = googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToICS(playermarker, latLng, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());

            }else{
                //playermarker.setPosition(latLng);
                MarkerAnimation.animateMarkerToICS(playermarker, latLng, new LatLngInterpolator.Spherical());


            }





            mydb.child("relics").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                HashMap<String,relic> relics= new HashMap();

                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Map<String,Integer> relicdistances = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

                    for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        relics.put(childSnapshot.getKey(), childSnapshot.getValue(relic.class));
                    }

                    for (Map.Entry<String, relic> entry : relics.entrySet()) {



Log.d("asd",relics.entrySet().toString());

                        LatLng latlngrelic;
                        latlngrelic = new LatLng(entry.getValue().getLatitude(), entry.getValue().getLongitude());
                        MarkerOptions relicmarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                        relicmarkerOptions.position(latlngrelic);
                        relicmarkerOptions.title(entry.getValue().getDrop());

                        Marker relicmarker = googleMap.addMarker(relicmarkerOptions);
                        hashMapMarker.put(entry.getKey(),relicmarker);


                        Log.d("asd","Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Latitude = " + entry.getValue().getLatitude() + entry.getValue().getLongitude());
                        int distance = (int) Math.floor(distance(location.getLatitude(),entry.getValue().getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),entry.getValue().getLongitude(),0,0));
                         relicdistances.put(entry.getKey().toString(),distance);


                    }
                    //Find the smallest relic distance key.(from relicdistances hashmap)
                    String minKey = null;
                    int minValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
                    for (String key : relicdistances.keySet()) {
                        int value = relicdistances.get(key);
                        if (value < minValue) {
                            minValue = value;
                            minKey = key;
                        }
                    }
                    minkeyglobal = minKey;

Log.d("minkey",minKey);
                    ///////
                    for (Map.Entry<String, relic> entry : relics.entrySet()) {
                        if(entry.getKey().equals(minKey)){
                            closestreliclatitude = entry.getValue().getLatitude();
                            closestreliclongitude = entry.getValue().getLongitude();
                            Log.d("closestreliclatitude",entry.getValue().getLatitude().toString());

                            break;
                        }


                    }
                    int closestrelicdistance = (int) Math.floor(distance(location.getLatitude(),closestreliclatitude,location.getLongitude(),closestreliclongitude,0,0));

if(closestrelicdistance <10){
    distancetext.setText("RELIC DETECTED! SHAKE YOUR PHONE TO DIG!!");
detected=true;


}else{
    detected = false;
    distancetext.setText("You are "+String.valueOf(closestrelicdistance)+" meters away from closest relic!");

}


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });




        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Losing GPS Signal...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0,0, locationListener);

}




    public void hearShake() {
        if(detected){
            detected = false;

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DIGGING",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Marker relicmarker = hashMapMarker.get(minkeyglobal);

            Log.e("relicmarkerrrrrrrr",relicmarker.toString());
            relicmarker.remove();
            Handler handler=new Handler(); // I added this for trying.After shaking, marker is removed succesfully but whenever 5 second passes and remove from db code triggers its added again.
            Runnable r=new Runnable() {       
                public void run() { 
                    mydb.child("relics").child(minkeyglobal).removeValue();
                }
            };
            handler.postDelayed(r, 5000);
            hashMapMarker.remove(minkeyglobal);



            detected = false;


        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No relic around!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
```

By the way remove db code is working.Its removing data from database succesfully.

Here there is a video of unexpected behaviour:
https://streamable.com/m7e90